# Cordova build android failed

Tags: android, linux, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on linux 14.04 OS and using Cordova to develop cross platform mobile apps

my system info is

> Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
>   Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
>   OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
>   Node Version: v5.10.1

I installed all android sdk required tools for API 20,21,22,23 and 24

then I run the following

```
 cordova platform add android
 cordova build android
```

each time I had the same error

> Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:599)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:566)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:563)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:562)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:559)
>       at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:109)
>       at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
>       at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
>       at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Script '/vagrant_data/newApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' >line: 64
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>     No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools >version 19.1.0 or higher.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -->debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.929 secs
>   Error: Error code 1 for command: >/vagrant_data/newApp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,->b,/vagrant_data/newApp/platforms/android/build.gradle,->Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

here is my PATH

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
~/android-sdk-linux:
~/android-sdk-linux/tools:
~/android-sdk-linux/platforms:
~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:
~/android-sdk-linux/build-tools: 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

any help will be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Why you write `cordova platform build android` and not `cordova build android`?

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach sorry I just typed incorrect in the question but I am using cordova build android

Comment: Your problem must be something with the android sdk.  Are you sure, that your installation is properly and that `ANDROID_HOME` is set to the correct sdk directory?

Comment: sure when I run android list target sdks are shown properly and no errors appear at all

Answer (score -1):

I think you should give path for tools, build-tools, platform- tools remove ~/android-sdk-linux/platforms: Try once and I am not getting where u are adding that java path like I have added JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\ jdk

Comment: tools is added in path and path to java is in the last line ... please check it again!